# What exactly does aria-controls do for the user? How is it affected by AJAX usage?

Tags: ajax, tabs, accessibility, wai-aria

I have a set of tabs with proper roles and attributes for accessibility support. The content that tab controls gets loaded in via ajax. But each wrapper for the content loaded in also has proper tab pane roles and attributes.

The problem is, when I run an automated audit using Chrome Accessibility Tools, the test fails stating that the corresponding `ID` of the tab pane is missing for all of the tabs except the one that's currently active (because that wrapper with ID has been loaded). The exact error states: "ARIA attributes which refer to other elements by ID should refer to elements which exist in the DOM."

Since the `ID` will exist once the tab with the corresponding `aria-controls` attribute is active, is this really an error? Or is this just a case of a false positive because it's an automated test and they can only do so much.

In summary, What does `aria-controls` do and does it really need to refer to an `ID` that currently exists in the DOM?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions

Comment: @epascarello I'm aware of live regions, but that link doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`aria-controls` give your assisting technology a way to move to the controlled element.

If this element is not in the DOM or can't be accessed, then yes it's an error.

Answer (score 1):

The two (the element with `aria-controls` as well the element with the referenced `id`) must exist at the same time, whether at page render or via JS injection.

The DOM is parsed by the UA/AT combo before the user even gets to the control or your script fires to make it exist. If you use JS injection then you need to make sure the DOM is re-parsed.

This would apply to `aria-owns` as well.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are suggesting that only adding the `aria-controls` property to the tab itself when it is active is acceptable?

Comment: No. At that point it is too late as the UA/AT combo has no idea that there is a relationship. Add it at page render. Doing it via JS injection is risky and may not be picked up unless the DOM is re-parsed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether the following would work in your architecture, but it would solve the error problem:
Design the tabs so they are all in the page at the time it loads. Format those that should not be shown to be outside the viewport using absolute positioning and something like "left: -99em." Use AJAX to reset the positioning when the time has come to display the tabs. The result is that the ARIA ID dependencies will always be valid because the tabs are always part of the DOM.